# Convert enum to string of it's name

Tags: ios, swift

If i have a `struct` like so:

```
struct Stuff: Codable {
    var id: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
        case id = "Banana"
    }
}
```

How can i convert `Stuff.CodingKeys.id` to produce a string `"id"` without hardcoding this as a switch somewhere?

Both `.stringValue` and `.rawValue` produce `Banana`.

**UPDATE**

I have found a solution on Swift forums that looks like this:

```
@_silgen_name("swift_EnumCaseName")
func _getEnumCaseName<T>(_ value: T) -> UnsafePointer<CChar>?

func getEnumCaseName<T>(for value: T) -> String? {
    if let stringPtr = _getEnumCaseName(value) {
        return String(validatingUTF8: stringPtr)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Works wonders, too.

However, can anybody confirm if this would be considered a private API that would fail an app review by Apple? My app is for iOS.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your actual problem that you're trying to solve for?

Comment: @NewDev i need to get the value out of a `class` which conforms to `Codable` using a string value of the CodingKey (e.g. `Banana` in this example).

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you said, but it sounds like a restatement of what you attempted to do here. Why do you think you need this? Or if it makes sense, add an example of your use case into the question.

Comment: @NewDev this question is fairly self contained and is even solvable as it turns out, so I will leave it as-is. For a broader one explaining what I meant above see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69096234/get-property-value-using-string-key-name