# Get property value using string key name

Tags: swift

Say I have a `Codable` like so:

```
struct Stuff: Codable {
    var id: String
    var coreRange: Bool
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
        case id = "Banana"
        case coreRange = "CR"
    }
}
```

If i have an instance like so

```
let x = Stuff(id: "42", coreRange: true)
```

Knowing only the word `Banana` how can I get `42` out of it?

This is for integration with a remote api where all they know is a string `Banana` with a value `Cheese` and i need to filter an array of my `Stuff` structs using that information (e.g. only those where `id` == `Cheese`).

Now in the real app there are some 50 properties on this struct and remote server can choose to filter on any of them.

Comment: You declare the enum class but never used it. What's the point of the enum class?

Comment: So, you have a json structure something like `{"Banana":"42", "CR":true}`?  But it could also be like `{"Cheese":"42", "CR":true}`?  I'd say you're screwed if this is the case, this is kind of a bad design and your only alternative would be to fall back to the good old `Dictionary` based parsing workflow

Comment: @RickyMo You do understand what `CodingKey` is and how it relates to `Codable` right?

Comment: @RickyMo yeah as MadProgrammer said this is for `Codable`

Comment: @MadProgrammer this is a bad design alright, it's Salesforce API :) Tbh i found that i can get values using `Mirror` but for that I need the text key of the enum to convert `Banana` to `id`, for which I have another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69096048/convert-enum-to-string-of-its-name?noredirect=1#comment122120984_69096048

Comment: @RickyMo  my every day :P

Comment: @zaitsman I don't think `Codable` is the solution you're looking for to solve this problem.  You're probably going to need to fall back to manually decoding and parsing the json.  Maybe have a look at [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: @MadProgrammer these models (classes/strucsts) are used in many other places and already coded to dictionaries and JSON, in this particular case the source is not even JSON but rather the data from SQLite db, i just need to extend this functionality

Comment: So if I understand this correctly you might get a condition like “Banana == 42” or “CR == true” and need to find any objects in some collection that matches the condition?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yup. it's enough to say that both are ok to evaluate as strings for simplicity (e.g. `"\(x.coreRange)" == "true"`)

Comment: To me it looks like you would need some kind of lookup table to translate from a string to a key path. It will probably be a pain to set up with over 50 properties but on the other hand  I think performance would be good.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson well yes that's basically all i am trying to avoid, coz i already have an enum so I would hope that reversing that could be possible. I gave up on performance for now and just implemented it via encoding objects to a dictionary. All up the inflexibility of Swift is getting on my nerves with lack of true reflection or true KVO